# How to send large video file to server in android

Tags: android, android-volley

Hi i am trying to upload large video files to server using Volley library but when i request big video files to server it's taking too large time and video not uploading there is server side limitation **4MB**

how can i resolve this problem please help me some one

### my code:

```
  RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
                final String url = Constants.SERVER_URL + serverUrl;

                MultipartAPI multipartAPI = new MultipartAPI(url, params, authenticationHeaders,fileType,fileMap, reqType,
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyErrorvolleyError) {
                                // progressDialog.dismiss();
                                if (volleyError != null) {

                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        System.out.println("------->" + response);

                    }
                });

                int socketTimeout = 450000;
                RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
                multipartAPI.setRetryPolicy(policy);
                queue.add(multipartAPI);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Define Progress bar displaying uploading progress

```
private ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

> Uploading the file to server

```
  private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Making progress bar visible
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // updating progress bar value
        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

        // updating percentage value
        txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("PHP FILE_UPLOAD_URL Here");

        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });

            File sourceFile = new File(" Your File Path");

            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

            // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
            entity.addPart("website",
                    new StringBody("www.androidhive.info"));
            entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("abc@gmail.com"));

            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

        // showing the server response in an alert dialog
        showAlert(result);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

> Method to show alert dialog

```
   private void showAlert(String message) 
   {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
   }
```

> Start uploading call

```
 new UploadFileToServer().execute();
```

Comment: i have to upload hole video using volley multiparet api

Comment: i am not sure your answer is related to my question

Comment: sorry, i will use large video upload HttpClient

Comment: even we use any library that's not matter here,have to upload big video files fastly

Comment: you will check this to server side  https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-site-performance/increase-upload-size-in-your-phpini if you want to upload file using volly lib  then it can server side issue

Comment: better to send splitting/chunk files

Comment: sorry i not understand

Comment: means we can splitting files and send to server one by one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143240/discussion-between-vishal-and-krish).